# Help ordering a result by date in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

Is there any way in SQLite to ORDER BY a date, and have result be ordered by time rather than alphabetically?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM details GROUP BY date;

John    |     Smith     |     April 01, 2011
John    |     Smith     |     April 03, 2011
John    |     Smith     |     April 04, 2011
John    |     Smith     |     March 25, 2011
```

March should come before April.

I'm guessing that the answer here is to store my dates as long timestamps, however I wasn't sure if it could be done more easily with SQLite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a built-in `DATE` type in SQLite (as exists in some other database management systems), but it does have a nice complement of date and time functions: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

You can use date("April 01, 2011") to get back an ISO-8601 date (e.g., 2011-04-01).

This format has the advantages of both being a readable string and being sortable. 2011-03-25 naturally comes before 2011-04-01 by standard string comparison rules, so there's no special operation required.

So, store your dates in that format, and get that format using the `date()` function (or other relevant function).

Comment: Easy enough, this did the trick for me.  Thanks so much for your explanation and help!

Comment: Thanks for the link, it saved me! It seems daft that SQLite allow you to create a column of type DATETIME if you can put "hello" into it! I have now discovered http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html at least.

Comment: I just had to post thank you to this, I've been searching and debugging for a solution as this for days. Very good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can convert date to an actual date in order to compare it.

try to add `order by julianday(date)` to the end of the query

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions

Answer (score 1):

date must be a string and not an actual date.  You would need to convert date to an actual date.  Here is a link to Sqlite date and time functions.
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
select * from sometable order by date(thestringDateColumn)
```

Hope this helps