# Order list of dates in String format

Tags: android, arrays, list, comparable

I've got a list which contains x records with dates. The thing is all my dates are in the String format and come as strings from the database.
I would really like to order my List by date (in String format) but I really have no clue how to do this.

Without further ado, this is my list, which is a custom list.

```
List<Finance> finances;
```

The list contains following fields:

```
public class Finance {
    private int id;
    private int categoryId;
    private int limitId;
    private double amount;
    private String date;
    private String description;
    }
```

And this is the dateformat I have (in String):
16/10/2013
15/12/2013
15/11/2013
14/9/2013

How would I be able to sort this custom list by date? I've seen many examples with Collections.sort but I cannot use that because of my custom list type.
I've also seen some examples with Comparable but I didn't really understand those..

Could anybody tell me what would be the best way to achieve a chronical order by date of mist list please?
I would also like the most lightweighted method, to use as little resources as I can.

EDIT: I still didn't find a working solution (19/12) and still hope for a response here..

Thank you
Yenthe

Comment: What( is the format of your dates ?

Comment: Example with a few records:
16/10/2013
15/12/2013
14/9/2013
So the days/month/year

Comment: Use both: A `Comparator` for comparing two `Finance` objects by their date. And use this `Comparator` to sort your `List<Finance>` with `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`.

Comment: @FabianBarney could you please write me a little example? And I do seem to see a problem already.. I wont be able to use Collections.Sort because my list is of a custom type. So how would I be able to work around that?

Comment: Your custom list should implement `java.util.List`. Then you can use all these methods with your custom list type. Show me what you've tried and I would post some code, too. But I don't see that you've even tried to write a Comparator for Finance objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since there where no good answers and barely any responses I decided to dig into it until I fixed it.

The 'easiest' way to come around this is to insert all your dates into the database as yyyy-mm-dd format. For a great explenation on that part you should look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733535/2262409

When you place the date in yyyy-mm-dd and just do a order by Date in your SQLite the dates will be ordered correct. When you place them in dd-mm-yyyy they will not be ordered correct.

Long answer short:
Solved it in the SQL part. I insert records in the format yyyy-mm-dd I get them by

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Finance ORDER BY date desc";
```

And then I reformat them to dd-mm-yyyy right before the user sees it. Example:

```
String date = String.valueOf(values.get(position).getDate());

// we will format yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy for readability.
//the sql has ordered our dates correctly already.
String firstPartDate = date.substring(8, 10);
String secondPartDate = "/" + date.substring(5,7);
String thirdPartDate = "/" + date.substring(0,4);
String fullCorrectDate = firstPartDate + secondPartDate + thirdPartDate;
Log.i("firstpart", firstPartDate + secondPartDate + thirdPartDate);

dateFinance.setText(fullCorrectDate);
```